Running SSH commands in Ruby with interactive login prompt
I want to execute commands on a remote target (via Ruby SSH). The login should be done with an interactive login prompt. This is what I got so far.
print('login: ')
user = $stdin.gets.chomp
Net::SSH.start(device_ip, user, port: device_port, verify_host_key: :never) do |session|
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.request_pty do |inner_channel, success|
      raise 'Failed to request pty' unless success

      inner_channel.send_channel_request('shell') do |inner_ch, inner_success|
        raise HIPC::ScriptingError, 'Failed to connect to the device' unless inner_success

        inner_ch.on_data do |_ch, data|
          print(data)
        end
        inner_ch.send_data("whoami\n")
        inner_ch.send_data("sudo whoami\n")
      end
    end
  end
end

The code runs without errors but I do not get any output of the whoami command or get asked for the sudo password. What do I wrong?

I believe you need to loop or this code just tears down everything you've created before the input arrives.

You probably want to use IO#expect if you're trying to deal with interactive prompts. Alternatively, you can just spawn an Expect script if you need to do really complex things that can't be done quite as easily in Ruby even with a PTY.
